# Test Maven plugin with maven-plugin-testing-harness

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I want to develop a Maven plugin and also *test* it properly. I was reading the documentation on [`maven-plugin-testing-harness`](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html) and trying things out for a few hours already. I'm constantly running into `NoClassDefFoundError` and `NoSuchMethodError`, I just can't figure out which dependencies I need.

Here's my MCVE:

https://github.com/highsource/hello-maven-plugin

Right now I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/descriptor/PluginDescriptorBuilder
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:161)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptorBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Here's the `pom.xml` of my plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hisrc.storyteller</groupId>
    <artifactId>storyteller-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>storyteller-maven-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`MyMojo.java` is trivial:

```
/**
 * Goal which touches a timestamp file.
 *
 * @goal touch
 * 
 * @phase process-sources
 */
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    /**
     * Location of the file.
     * 
     * @parameter expression="${project.build.directory}"
     * @required
     */
    private File outputDirectory;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        // Simply creates a touch.txt file in outputDirectory
    }
}
```

The test:

```
public class MyMojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testSomething()
        throws Exception
    {
        File pom = getTestFile( "src/test/resources/org/hisrc/storyteller/pom.xml" );
        assertNotNull( pom );
        assertTrue( pom.exists() );

        MyMojo myMojo = (MyMojo) lookupMojo( "touch", pom );
        assertNotNull( myMojo );
        myMojo.execute();
    }
}
```

`pom.xml` for the test:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.hisrc.storyteller</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-to-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test MyMojo</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>storyteller-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/test-harness/project-to-test</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I change the version of the `maven-plugin-api` to `3.0`, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.ContainerConfiguration.setClassPathScanning(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/plexus/ContainerConfiguration;
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainerConfiguration(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:285)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:259)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.getContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:152)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I've looked around and all I see is that people seem to add some random dependencies, sometimes things work sometimes not. I've spent a few hours trying to do the same but did not manage to make it work. I'm quite desperate at the moment and hope that someone eventually figured it out and could point me to the correct dependencies and/or versions.

Comment: Which Maven command do you execute? I think the main problem may be the maven-plugin-api dependency with version 2.0, which seems to be quite outdated and incompatible to the other dependencies...

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht `mvn clean install`

Comment: Sorry, just read that you tried maven-plugin-api 3.0. But have you tried 3.3.9, the same version as for the other dependencies?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Nothing to be sorry about. :) You happend to be right, that was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

@FlorianAlbrecht was right, I had to specify the same version (`3.3.9`) for Maven dependencies. This is what I ended up with:

```
<properties>
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: One might also need this addition to the pom configuration of the Maven plugin under test https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998870/261378