# AssertionFailedError: Maven 3.2.4 or better is required (running version 3.2.5)

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

In Maven, I am trying to build my custom plugin with unit tests (using `maven-surefire-plugin`), but I am getting the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.038 sec <<< FAILURE!
testSomething(com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Maven 3.2.4 or better is required
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:149)
    at com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest.setUp(dddTest.java:40)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   testSomething(com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest): Maven 3.2.4 or better is required

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.950 s
```

important line being:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Maven 3.2.4 or better is required
```

But when I check the version, I see:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5
```

If I skip the tests using `-DskipTests`, it is building fine. Why is this error happening? Maybe there is some dependency that I am using that requires Maven 3.2.5? And why is it not detecting the correct version?

Any help/suggestions will be very helpful.

P.S. This error started happening after I added one particular mojo. If I remove the Mojo, it is building fine. What in the Mojo could be causing it?

---

**EDIT:**

I removed the `Setup()` from `dddTest.java`, and I am still getting the same error, just without specifying the line. New error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Maven 3.2.4 or better is required
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:149)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT 2:**

I saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224885/test-maven-plugin-with-maven-plugin-testing-harness) and I realize that there is some problem with dependency versions. So I updated the versions of maven dependencies mentioned on the link and then some more (based on comparing dependency tree with maven central). Each time I update the version, the error changes (but still occurs during testing). And now I am facing the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.ContainerConfiguration.setClassPathScanning(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/plexus/ContainerConfiguration;
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainerConfiguration(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:285)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:259)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.getContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:152)
    at com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest.setUp(dddTest.java:39)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
```

Dependency Tree for this error:

```
+- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.5:provided
 +- org.apache.maven.plugin-testing:maven-plugin-testing-harness:jar:3.3.0:test
 |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
 |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.2:test
 |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.4:test
 +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22:compile
 |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
 +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.22:compile
 |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
 +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:compile
 +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:3.0.0:compile
 |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.7:compile
 +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.3.9:provided
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.3.9:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
 |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.0:compile
 |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
 |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:compile
 |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
 |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
 +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
 +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-exec:jar:1.3:compile
 |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile
 |  \- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
 +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
 +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.7.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.7:compile
 |  \- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
 |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
 \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.3:compile
    +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:compile
    |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
    \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.3:compile
```

Any suggestion on which dependency version should I be changing?

Comment: It looks like one of your tests is checking something...

Comment: I would look there... `com.aaa.bbb.maven.plugin.eee.dddTest.setUp`, line 40.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz edited the question with new error after removing `setUp`

Comment: @khmarbaise edited the question with new error after removing `setUp`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following dependencies:

```
...
<properties>
    <maven.version>3.5.0</maven.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

Based on this blog post from Vincent Zurczak: https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/write-unit-tests-for-a-maven-plug-in/

When I set the scope of `org.apache.maven:maven-core` to *test*, as in Zurczak's example, it broke the build because I'm using `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject` in my mojo.